# Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 bootloop after trying to flash TWRP, boot partition is damaged, unable to boot into recovery or fastboot

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, fastboot, boot-loop, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 (128GB/4GB RAM). I have unlocked my bootloader. Then I tried to install TWRP. I got into the fastboot mode, then executed:

```
fastboot devices
fastboot flash recovery [file].img
fastboot flash vbmeta [file2].img
fastboot flash misc [file3].bin
reboot
```

or something like it. And when I push the volume(-) and power buttons while rebooting, it just reboots into the Xiaomi logo, again. I can not even turn it off.

Now, it is stuck on a bootloop showing the Xiaomi logo. I am unable to boot into the bootloader. When I connected it to the PC and tried to boot into the bootloader -with no success-, the PC made the sound of something being connected but it quickly made the sound of something being disconnected.

What should I do?

Note: I am a complete newbie in this.

I went to different repair shops and they told me it needs software or worse a new ROM.

Comment: "I am unable to boot into the bootloader" - how do you try to enter bootloader mode? Have you tried pressing Power+Volume while booting?

Comment: I tried pressing Power+Volume "down " while booting

Comment: And what commands did you execute to get the device into that state? Please edit your question and add all the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the phone.
I got out of "EDL stuck".
I bypassed the authentication.
Then I used SP Flash Tool to flash a new ROM using a firmware upgrade.
Its bootloader is locked again.
Now the phone is unbricked.

Comment: Where could I find a tutorial on how to do that? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone has a MediaTek chipset, and there is a tool available on GitHub called [MTKClient](http://www.github.com/bkerler/mtkclient), which you can use for this purpose. This procedure is irreversible so you should read well and comply strictly with the instructions of the manual. I recommend deleting the recovery partition and then rebooting the device using `python mtk e recovery` command.

Comment: How will this solve my problem, can u explain?